# Unable to remove global installation of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have followed the standard procedure (`npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and
`yarn global remove create-react-app`) to remove my previous global installation of create-react-app using yarn as shown in the screenshot below. I have also checked that the following directory does not exist: /usr/local/bin/create-react-app.

However, I still get errors when using `npx create-react-app myapp`, saying that I am running create-react-app 4.0.0.

```
which create-react-app
```

also outputs nothing.

Hence, I am looking for a way to resolve this issue.
[image: Screenshot of terminal]

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have it installed locally in the current folder you’re in?

Comment: I would like to close my question if I can, but I do not have enough rep. Since I have deleted this VM, I will not be able to check if the proposed solutions work.

Comment: I’ve flagged it for the moderators to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the NPM cache:

```
npm config get cache | xargs ls -tr | grep create-react-app
```

If it shows anything, delete it:

```
npm config get cache | xargs ls -tr | grep create-react-app | xargs rm -rf
```

If this still fails, try installing the latest stable version:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Also, if it still doesn't work with `npx`, try with instead `npm`:

```
npm create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply! Unfortunately, I have deleted this instance of my VM already and have reverted to a backup, so I would not be able to verify if this works.

Comment: This is a good idea but the real issue is they were probably using node 18. I just ran into this issue and this thread. The npm cache solution didn't fix it for me but what did was switching to v16.17 of node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using node 18. Change your node version to LTS to run into less issues. A lot of modern packages use LTS as their dependency, not node 18.

**To Do:**
Download node LTS (Right now - 16.17.1). I would recommend doing it through homebrew and download the "nvm" package. `brew install nvm`

Then run `nvm` to make sure you get a output from the terminal. If you don't see any output, try installing nvm again through homebrew or other debugging methods.

Then go to your root (on mac `cd ~`) and run `nvm ls-remote` and that will show you a long list. You only care about LTS, items highlighted, and the very latest versions.

`nvm install v16.17.1`

Check you have the correct version, `node -v`. If it still shows the newer version run a `nvm use v16.17.1` but usually they set it as your default.

With nvm you can also set profiles, switch between LTS and other versions. Sometimes you might want to use node 12 on a docker container. That is the benefit of having a tool like nvm.